# Can't get order_by meta_value_num to work properly

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, php, wp-query

This query is working ALMOST as intended, but for some reason I can't get it to order by the custom field `opl_submission_tempo`. That field is set up to be a number, so I'm not sure where I went wrong here.

```
$tempo_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
      'post_type'       => 'opl_tempo_submission',
      'order_by'        => 'meta_value_num',
      'meta_key'        => 'opl_submission_tempo',
      'order'           => 'ASC',
      'posts_per_page'  => 1,
      'meta_query'      => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
          'key' => 'opl_submission_exercise_type',
          'value' => $exercise_type,
          'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
          'key' => 'opl_submission_exercise_number',
          'value' => $exercise_number,
          'compare' => '='
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Comment: This looks correct to me. I double checked [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) and it looks like you've done it correctly. What sort of debugging have you tried? eg. does it order by other values correctly? Is it something to do with this particular field?

Comment: Tested it without the metaquery and cant get ordering to work. Please enlighten us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `order_by`. Change `order_by` to [`orderby`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) and it should work.

The default value of `compare` is `=` so it is unnecessary, you can remove it. Also, you should specify `type` of the `meta_value` if it is a specific type rather than the default `CHAR`.

Comment: Yep that was the issue.